# Sorting data by time with custom start time

Tags: ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm building a timetable app using Rails and I need to order some records by time, however I want the start time to be say 05:00 rather than 00:00

My query looks like this:

@timetable_entries.order(departure_time: :asc)

result:

```
00:30
03:30
05:30
...
```

however I want my day to start at 5am so the resulting data should look like this:

```
05:30
00:30
03:30
```

Doe anyone know a clean way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is it mean you need sort time by next day? 
e.i: 
05:30 -> 2019/03/10
00:30 -> 2019/03/11

Comment: What is the data type of the `departure_time` column?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this would probably be to write your own comparator. The ruby `sort` method can take a block ([documentation here](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort)) that allows you to sort using a custom comparison method. You can use that method to indicate that 5:00 is earlier than everything from 0:00 to 4:59.

The code would look something like:

```
@timetable_entries.sort do |time1, time2|
  # your custom comparison here
end
```

Comment: Good idea, but you need to include the block corresponding to a start time of `05:30`.

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = %w| 00:30 03:30 00:01, 05:30 10:20 02:10 14:05 19:06 |
  #=> ["00:30", "03:30", "00:01,", "05:30", "10:20", "02:10", "14:05", "19:06"]
```

```
sorted = arr.sort
  #=> ["00:01,", "00:30", "02:10", "03:30", "05:30", "10:20", "14:05", "19:06"] 
idx = sorted.find_index { |s| (s <=> '05:30') >= 0 }
  #=> 4  
sorted.rotate(idx)
  #=> ["05:30", "10:20", "14:05", "19:06", "00:01,", "00:30", "02:10", "03:30"]
```

See [Array#find_index](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html#method-i-find_index), [String#<=>](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/String.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E) and [Array#rotate](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html#method-i-rotate).

Another way follows.

```
arr.sort_by { |s| (s <=> '05:30') == -1 ? "#{s[0,2].to_i+24}:#{s[2,3]}" : s }
```

If `s = '02:10'`,

```
s <=> '05:30'  #=> -1
a = s[0,2]     #=> "02" 
b = a.to_i     #=> 2 
c = b+24       #=> 26 
d = s[2,3]     #=> ":10" 
"#{c}:#{d}"    #=> "26::10"
```

See [Enumerable#sort_by](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by).

Comment: It looks like OP is trying to sort database records using ActiveRecord's `order` clause, not trying to sort a plain Ruby array.

Comment: @Jordan, I see what you mean. I'd translate my answer if I knew `ActiveRecord`, but I don't. Perhaps my answer will be of use to someone who wishes to post an answer that employs `ActiveRecord`.